# Why textarea higher than text input?

Tags: html, css

Found it, sorry, changed padding and forgot to change it for textarea.
My mistake. Will delete )

I'm trying to make table with text input and textarea input on the same row, but cannot make textarea the same height as the text input.
Could anyone please tell me, why text input and textarea have different height and how to fix that? As you can see, textarea is 2px higher and chrome inspector tells me the same. What's wrong and how to fix that?
(sorry for a large text, site told me that I've got "mostly code" and have to add some details. Have no idea, what else may I add to that code, the problem is obvious)))
Thank you!

```css
div
{
    background: #ddd;
}
input#te
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea#ta
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type=text id="te" value="input is 2px smaller in chrome">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <textarea id="ta">textarea is 2px higher in chrome</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Comment: Padding, mostly. top/bottom

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; - on the text area

Answer (score 4):

the textarea has padding top-bottom 2px,

the input only 1px.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know why this is the case, in terms of UI theory, or is it a glitch? The SELECT element also has variation curiosities. The lack of apparent sizing/spacing consistency between INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA confuses non-CSS-specialists, such as a typical full-stack-developer who can't realistically be a master-of-all-trades.

Answer (score 2):

change the padding on textarea:

```css
div
{
    background: #ddd;
}
input#te
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea#ta
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding: 1px 0.5em;        
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type=text id="te" value="input is 2px smaller in chrome">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <textarea id="ta">textarea is 2px higher in chrome</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem, add `box-sizing: border-box` to the input element AND to the textarea element (for the fix to work in Chrome).

```css
div {
  background: #ddd;
}
input#te {
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a78;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea#ta {
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a78;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  height: 5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type=text id="te" value="input is 2px smaller in chrome">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <textarea id="ta">textarea is 2px higher in chrome</textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`box-sizing: border-box;` is what you need to place onto the input and text area. Also works well for select.

By using `box-sizing: border-box;` it means you dont have to adjust all of your widths, padding and line-height and you can have everything the same

```css
div
{
    background: #ddd;
}
input#te
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea#ta
{
    position: relative;
    outline:0;
    border: 1px solid #a78;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type=text id="te" value="input is 2px smaller in chrome">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <textarea id="ta">textarea is 2px higher in chrome</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```